# Mixing categorical and continuous data in pure Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

How do I take categorical and continuous data from a CSV file (such as the [Titanic dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic)) and get it into a good format for Tensorflow without using the tf.learn API (i.e. pure Tensorflow)?

For example,

- Categorical data might be (in my case) 'vehicle_make', 'vehicle_model'
- Continuous data might be 'price', 'mileage'

I then want to use this data as input to a multilayer perceptron neural network as in the following example:

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.ipynb

Cheers,

Baz

Answer (score 3):

You can use one-hot encoding for categorical data.

Basically you can map vehicle_model to numerical value

Tesla S -> 1

Ford Focus -> 2

... -> i

And then use vector with all zeros and 1 in i-th position to represent that value:

Tesla S -> [1, 0, 0]

Ford Focus -> [0, 1, 0]

both [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#one_hot) and [scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) have functions to do that.

Include continious data as-is, as one of values of input vector.

Comment: Do I need to scale the continuous values to be between 0 and 1 say?  If so how do you recommend doing that?  Cheers.

Comment: Normalizing input data is almost always a sensible step to do, just make sure all data is normalized in the same way and testing data does not 'leak' any information to trainig sets e.t.c.